# asp.net textbox not rendering wider than 300px

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I am trying to setup my EditItemTemplate for a FormView and my "Notes" textbox will not render any larger than about 300px wide regardless of how I code the width for it.

Currently marked up as:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="NotesTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" style="width:600px" Text='<%# Bind("Notes") %>'/>
```

If I adjust the style width below 300px, I have some wiggle room to resize. If I go any higher, the textbox won't budge horizontally. Vertical resize is fine. I tried enclosing it in a `<table style=width:100%">` just to be sure it wasn't inside something that would be capping it, but same results. I tried adjusting Columns=XX and I get more or less the same results at Columns=40. Vertical adjustment is fine, but horizontal adjustment won't go beyond 300px/40cols/3 inches on screen.

For what it's worth, the related Label on the ItemView has no defined width and it stretches across the whole form which is ideally what I'd like the TextBox to do. Without any defined width, the TextBox renders at about 160px wide.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to make the textbox go any wider.

Comment: I'm not sure if the asp.net textbox style attribute is valid?.. I usually use the CssClass attribute so that I can apply styles in css and keep the styling separate

Comment: Please post the **rendered** HTML for this control.

Comment: <textarea name="ctl00$MainContent$FormView1$NotesTextBox" rows="5" cols="20" id="MainContent_FormView1_NotesTextBox" class="NotesBox" style="width:600px">Text from Notes</textarea>

Comment: My first paste of the rendered html was from a cached page. I closed out and refreshed and the above HTML is what is behind the control after refreshing.

Comment: in reference to the first comment of the CssClass suggestion, I tried that as well. With the rendered page up, I can adjust the width and immediately see the change on the page. Any value over 300px does not display the box any wider on the page. Less than 300 and the box shrinks accordingly and I can move the resize anchor to a max width matching 300 px.

Comment: In cases like this, the developer tools in whatever browser you are using will be invaluable, since the issue you are having is with rendering, and that's the browser's job.  Each browser's tools are a bit different but they all provide the same basic functionality, and what would be helpful for you are to view the calculated layout and applied CSS rules of your textbox and any parent elements.  I'd set the textarea width to 100%, then view the calculated layout of it and all parents.

Comment: Do you have any width restrictions on your FormView element?

Comment: No restrictions on FormView.

'<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ProjectID" DataSourceID="ProjectDetailsSQL" ForeColor="#333333">'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. I wasn't looking far enough in my Inspect Element window. Site.css had `textarea { max-width: 280px; }`

I changed my CssClass for my NotesBox to `{ max-width: 100%; }` and it looks just fine.